# Angular app in google app engine redirection issue

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy angular 7 app in app engine
Used `ng deploy --prod` to create deployment. Now deployed generated `dist` using app.yaml. 
Content of app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

  - url: /
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
  - url: /
    static_dir: dist
  - url: /\w{3,}-?[^.\s]\w*
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
```

This works perfectly fine if URL is unchanged i.e. `domain.com` but when url changed to `domain.com/login` or `domain.com/profile` then it generated 404 error

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL /admin-dashboard was not found on this server.
```

To resolve redirection, I have added url pattern in app.yaml to match any urls and forward to `dist/index.html`

```
- url: /\w{3,}-?[^.\s]\w*
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
```

But that is not helping. I am totally stuck. Please any pointer
**@Christopher Peisert** thanks a lot for your pointer. Here is the final app.yaml works for all types of URL patterns

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
- url: /\w+$
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
- url: /(\w+-\w+)$
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html  
- url: /(.*)$
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a catch-all URL handler after the default route:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

- url: /(.*)$
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)
```

See documentation on [Handlers Element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element).

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for your help. But that does not seem to work. Here is my updated app.yaml file ```runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

  - url: /(.*\.(html|htm|map|js))$
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/.*\.(html|htm|map|js)$
  - url: /assets/
    static_dir: dist/assets ``` for urls ```domain.com``` it worked. But for ```domain.com/login``` it generated 404 error. I think I need a regex to match directory like /login to forward to /index.html. Any pointer

Comment: THanks. I finally updated app.yaml to work on any url patterns. @Christopher Peisert

Comment: I am facing ```page can’t be found``` error for php files. Here is the handler ```- url: /(.*)php
  script: www/mail.php ``` the php script very much exists, then why it generated page not found error??

Comment: @CoolCoder Try `- url: (.*\.(php))$`

Comment: @ Christopher Peisert , I dont think its issue with url pattern because it works perfectly when I try locally using dev_appserver.py app.yaml

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using PathLocationStrategy (html5 history) you need to have a handler to catch those dynamic routes

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
# index files
- url: /([^.]+)/?$  # urls with no dot in them
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

# site root
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

# everything else
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)
```